# Convert date string using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have date strings similar to type of the following format,

> 7-Dec-16

How can I convert it to the format given below using python??

> 2016-12-07

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strptime` from `datetime`

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_formatted = datetime.strptime('7-Dec-16', '%d-%b-%y')

print (datetime_formatted)
```

You can see in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for the usage of all directives.

> %b    Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
>
> %d    Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
>
> %y    Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

```
import dateparser
dateparser.parse('7-Dec-16').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Output :  `'07-12-2016'`

you can use `dateparser` library for multiple function.
[link](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

For your case you can get accurate answer by:

`dateparser.parse('7-Dec-16').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: Whats wrong with my answer.